# What data strucutre does *mutableSetOf()* return in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, collections, constructor, set

Is it implemented as a HashSet, linked HashSet or binary search tree?

I know it is hidden for encapsulation, but I need to estimate the asymptotic runtime.

Comment: If you need a specific implementation call that explicitly. What `mutableSetOf` returns is an implementation detail which can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up the implementation in my kotlin stdlib installation:

> ```
> public inline fun <T> mutableSetOf(): MutableSet<T> = LinkedHashSet()
> ```

Comment: Interestingly the documentation to mutableSetOf states: "Returns an empty new MutableSet. The returned set preserves the element iteration order." I believe only the LinkedHashSet preserves the iteration order.

Answer (score 3):

It can be interesting and instructive to look at the standard library's source code — but what `mutableSetOf()` *happens* to return today doesn't really matter, because that can change in future Kotlin versions.

The important thing is that [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html) doesn't mention a class, just the `MutableSet` interface.  That's all that JetBrains have committed to, and so that's all you can safely assume.  **You should never rely on a particular implementation choice, when that's not part of the contract.**

(The only other thing they specify is that ‘The returned set preserves the element iteration order.’  So you know it can't return a `HashSet`, which doesn't.  But that still leaves several current possibilities, and potentially many more in future.  Oracle or JetBrains may come up with a new implementation that has better general or worst-case performance, or some other desirable feature.)

Downcasting the result to a `LinkedHashSet` might work today, but in a future Kotlin version that might fail with a `ClassCastException`.  (Or even worse, it might work *most* of the time, and then throw a `ClassCastException` when you're not expecting it.)

So, **if you have particular performance requirements, then you're better off creating the type you want explicitly.**

`mutableSetOf()` is for when you *don't* have specific requirements, and just want something easy that's likely to behave well in general.